# Saving fingerprint data into database

Tags: java, android, sql-server, android-studio

I am creating an android project for my college, and there I want to make something like fingerprint attendance system using mobile fingerprint sensor, so actually I want to save biometric data into database for further reference during attendance.
I want to save fingerprint data into MS SQL database which is taken from the mobile fingerprint sensor.

Comment: The fact you want to save it in SQL Server adds a big layer of concern for security. SQL Server doesn't run on Android, meaning that you would be storing people's biometric data elsewhere that others have access to. Storing such data in a database like that comes with a huge wealth of security considerations, and you would certainly need to make people aware that their biometric data is being sent, via the internet, to an external location. Security would have to be a very high consideration to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store/collect fingerprint image/data from android's fingerprint sensor. The fingerprint data is encrypted on the file system (Trusted Execution Environment).

All you can do is, authenticate the user if the fingerprint is registered on the device